# Binary to Octal

Tags: c++, string, binary, octal

How to write code that converters a input file of binary numbers into octal. I had to write a code that converts it to decimal which I did, but now I'm supposed to write a code that converts it to octal by grouping the binary numbers in groups of 3 and then calling the binary to decimal function.

For example 10100 would be grouped 10 | 100. So I'd call binary to decimal on 10 and 100 and get 2 for 10 and 4 for 100, then place the numbers together to get 24, which is 10100 decimal in octal.

However, I cannot figure out how to group the numbers. (The number is type string by the way). Any tips would help thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: I tried adding a for loop that counts to 3, but if its not divisible by 3 it will assign a random value in the string[ i ] that does not really exist

Comment: please add your code example and the case that you can't get it right  ...

Answer (score 0):

Simply add leading zeroes to your string if its length is not divisble by three then group them and convert to octal.